# SQL Database for SQL practise

Tags: sql, database

For some time now I'm looking for sample (relational) databases (.SQL) so I can import it to my local MySQL server and play with some some SQL queries. Anyone know source, or can share exemplary database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

[ClassicModels](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx)

[Sakila](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/index.html), [download page for sakila and others](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html)

[NorthWind](http://www.pwsdb.com/pgm/?p=76)

for World database, see download page above.